# Partial derivative on chain rule

Tags: partial-derivative

Could anyone please guide me whether the solution of this partial derivative is correct?

Solution from reference material:

[image: Solution from reference material]

I have tried to calculate my own solution but it is different.

My calculation:

[image: My Calculation]

Take the case of two functions with two variables each

[image: limit2]

The solution of reference material, which is using summation to add

1. both results of dy/dx_1
2. both results of dy/dx_2

[image: solution1]
[image: solution2]

May i know the theory behind it? Can we just simply add both results together?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you did. Why is your partial derivative a vector?

Comment: Dear Mr Klaus, i am not so sure about the solution. Could you please guide me if the solution from reference material is correct? Thank you

Comment: The solution from the reference looks good. Are you asking why it's correct?

Comment: Mr CW279, yes correct. I couldn't find a way to match my calculation to the solution of reference material

Comment: Recommendation: Take the case  of two functions with two variables each and show where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: Mr Kurt G. , Thank you so much for your recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution for the two-variable case is on the right track, but there is no "or" in the derivative $\partial y/\partial x_1$. Since both $u_1$ and $u_2$ are functions of $x_1$, you have to add their contributions together:

$\qquad
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_1}=\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u_1}\,\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}+\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u_2}\,\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}
\end{equation}
$

Of course, similar considerations apply to $\partial y/\partial x_2$, and to the case of $n$ independent variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

Comment: Mr CW279, Thank you so much for your guidance.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!